# Is there way to extend jQuery to handle a custom enter key event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I write the following code all the time to handle when the enter key pressed:

```
$("#selectorid").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var targetType = e.originalTarget
            ? e.originalTarget.type.toLowerCase()
            : e.srcElement.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (targetType != "textarea") {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            // code to handler enter key pressed
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a way to extend jQuery so that I could just write:

```
$("#selectorid").enterKeyPress(fn);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend jquery something like:

```
jQuery.fn.returnPress = function(x) {
  return this.each(function() {
    jQuery(this).keypress(function(e) {
      if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
        x();
        return false;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Which can be invoked like:

```
$('selector').returnPress(function() { alert('enter pressed'); });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do what David G says, but perhaps the most correct way to approach this would be to write a custom event:

```
$(document).keypress(function(evt){
    if(evt.keyCode==13) $(evt.target).trigger('enterPress');
});
```

Which could be bound like so:

```
$(document).bind('enterPress', fn);
```

See an example here: http://jquery.nodnod.net/cases/1821/run

The advantage to this approach is that you can bind, unbind, namespace, and trigger the event like any other event in jQuery.

Comment: Of course, evt.target doesn't work in IE. Use evt.srcElement in those cases.

Comment: @cpharmston: the code is using jQuery. `.target` works in jQuery.

Comment: +1 for being the only solution (so far) which actually uses a custom event.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can define it as a plugin with a bit less code like this:

```
jQuery.fn.enterKeyPress = function(callback) {
  return this.not("textarea").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      callback($(this));
      return false;
    }
  });
};
```

Use like this:

```
$("input").enterKeyPress(function() { alert('hi'); });
```

This approach still ignores `<textarea>`, but instead of checking every keystroke, we just never bind the `keypress` event to any textarea.

Comment: this.not("textarea") will not work because 'this' will be the form. not the input. The rest works :)

Comment: @Ken - Judging by your answer, it seemed like you'd be binding this to a textbox or other input.  You could bind this format with delegate however, and it'd capture all keypress events not in a textbox like your question, e.g. `$("#formId :input")` as the selector.

Comment: Events bubble up. The original target would be the input but the event will be handled at a container div (or form.) Sorry the ambiguity I should have made the question clearer. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Nice answer, is it then possible to enable `bind("click","enterKeyPress"` then?

Comment: Not in this case, well you can but it wouldn't do anything because it's not firing that event.  You could create a `.live()` handler for all elements that did `$('textarea').keypress(function(e) { if (e.keyCode == 13) { $(e.target).trigger('enterKeyPres'); } });` if you wanted it as an event, with that in place then you could bind it, `.bind('enterKeyPress', myfunction);` :).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to capture the enter key on any form element, and convert it into a tab.  I have made it so the enter key works normally in a textarea, and on submit, reset and button elements.

```
$.fn.focusNext = function(e) {
  var t = $(this);
  if ( t.is(":submit")==true || t.is(":reset")==true || t.is("textarea")==true || t.is("button")==true ) { exit(); }

  if (e.which==13 || e.which==3) {
    return this.each(function() {
      e.preventDefault();
      var fields = $(this).parents("form:eq(0)").find(":input:visible");
      var index = fields.index( this );
      if ( index > -1 && ( index + 1 ) < fields.length ) { fields.eq( index + 1 ).focus(); }
    });
  }
  return true;
};
```

And to use it, it's called like so

```
$(":input").keypress(function(e) { $(this).focusNext(e); });
```

OR

```
$(":input").live("keypress", function(e) { $(this).focusNext(e); });
```